# Ruby 3.3 introduces yield error when using ruby -c syntax check

Tags: erb, ruby-3

I use `erb` with `ruby -c` to syntax check erb files.
How I do it:

```bash
cat layout.html.erb | erb -x -T '-' | ruby -c
```

For example this `layout.html.erb` file:

```
<div class="container">
 <%= yield %>
</div>
```

Up until `ruby 3.2` it always worked, meaning

```bash
# ruby 2.5, ruby 2.7.2, ruby 3.2
cat layout.html.erb | erb -x -T '-' | ruby -c
# => Syntax OK
```

But introducing `ruby 3.3` we get an error:

```bash
# ruby 3.3
cat layout.html.erb | erb -x -T '-' | ruby -c
# => -:3: Invalid yield
# => ; _erbout.<<(( yield ).to_s); _erbout.<< "\n".fre...
# => -: compile error (SyntaxError)
```

For now I worked around it by removing the lines containing `yield`, using `grep -v yield`:

```bash
cat layout.html.erb | grep -v yield | erb -x -T '-' | ruby -c
```

Can you think of a different way of syntax checking a `ruby 3.3` erb file containing `yield`?